# Is it legal to pass 'document' into MutationObserver.observe()?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, standards, mutation-observers

The [MDN documentation for `MutationObserver.observe()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe) states that the first parameter passed into `observe()` should be "A DOM Node (which may be an Element) within the DOM tree to watch for changes, or to be the root of a subtree of nodes to be watched."  All the examples I've seen for high-level DOM observation advise passing in `document.body` here, but can you actually pass in `document` instead to observe both the body and head in one observer (or for that matter, observe the `body` once it's added, if the `body` does not yet exist at the time your JS is executing)?

This seems to work in Chrome, but is that non-standard behaviour by Chrome or is it legal according to the spec?

Comment: Easy enough to find out: `document instanceof Node` is true and [a description of the `Document` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) says it inherits from `Node`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is that it is totally possible/legal to pass `document` into `observe()`.  My guess as to why guides usually pass `document.body` in is simply to avoid observing unwanted mutations of the `head` and also potentially DOM elements that haven't yet been attached to the body.